# You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlhttprequest, webrequest, webresponse

Error:
You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse.

Can anyone advise why I am getting the above error when running the following code

```
        Dim xml As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()

        Dim root As XmlElement
        root = xml.CreateElement("root")
        xml.AppendChild(root)

        Dim username As XmlElement
        username = xml.CreateElement("UserName")
        username.InnerText = "xxxxx"
        root.AppendChild(username)

        Dim password As XmlElement
        password = xml.CreateElement("Password")
        password.InnerText = "xxxx"
        root.AppendChild(password)

        Dim shipmenttype As XmlElement
        shipmenttype = xml.CreateElement("ShipmentType")
        shipmenttype.InnerText = "DELIVERY"
        root.AppendChild(shipmenttype)


        Dim url = "xxxxxx"
        Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
        req.Method = "POST"
        req.ContentType = "application/xml"
        req.Headers.Add("Custom: API_Method")
        req.ContentLength = xml.InnerXml.Length

        Dim newStream As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
        xml.Save(newStream)

        Dim response As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()


        Console.Write(response.ToString())
```

Comment: maybe this helps: http://forums.asp.net/t/1956377.aspx?How+to+fix+this+error+You+must+write+ContentLength+bytes+to+the+request+stream+before+calling+Begin+GetResponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a length mismatch between the character length of `xml.InnerXml` and what is actually written to the stream in `xml.Save(newStream)`.  Check if `InnerXml` includes the xml version node, for example.  Also, I don't see you specifying a character encoding, which definitely affects the size on the wire.  Perhaps you need to save to a temporary memory stream, get the length of that, and then send that in the request.

Answer (score 1):

In short: `newStream.Length != xml.InnerXml.Length`.

- First of all, `XmlDocument.Save(Stream)` will encode the response, which may result in a different number of bytes than are chars in the `.InnerXml` string.
- `.InnerXML` does not necessarily contain other stuff, such as the XML preamble.

Here is a complete example. (Sorry, my VB is a bit rusty, so C# instead):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

namespace xmlreq
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var xml = new XmlDocument();
      var root = xml.CreateElement("root");
      xml.AppendChild(root);

      var req = WebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/");
      req.Method = "POST";
      req.ContentType = "application/xml";

      using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        xml.Save(ms);
        req.ContentLength = ms.Length;
        ms.WriteTo(req.GetRequestStream());
      }
      Console.WriteLine(req.GetResponse().Headers.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried the above and now get This stream does not support seek operations.

Comment: Then just use a MemoryStream intermediary.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but what to you mean by use a MemoryStream?

Comment: Added sample (in C# :p) to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. Now getting this error <property cannot be set after writing has started> on the req.ContentLength = ms.Length line.

Comment: Error says it all... I'd guess: move the GetRequestStream below the ContentLength assignment.

Comment: Must be something to do with the web service I am trying to get to. Your code works fine but when I substitute the url to the one we need to access I get the original error. No sure why.

Comment: Sorted . problem with web service. Only problem now is to get the memorystream results into an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error today and the issue was that the endpoint provider had been redirecting http requests to https for years, but changed their policy. So updating my code from

```
request = WebRequest.Create("http://api.myfaxservice.net/fax.php")
```

to

```
request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.myfaxservice.net/fax.php")
```

did the trick. If the provider would have just shut off http, I think it would have been an easier problem to run down as this error was putting me on the wrong track.